# Procedure to track down font files

Tags: css, fonts

What is a procedure for tracking down where a font file is coming from? The only way I know is brute force -- looking through all the CSS files for `@font-face`  or `@import` declarations, and if none are found, checking through the JS files to see if there's anything that attaches other CSS files to the `head`, or if the JS files have anything else pertaining to fonts, etc.

For a concrete example, from whence comes the `"LucidaGrande"` in the top links on the following site? http://rmu.edu/supporting-rmu

(Don't worry: I'm not trying to steal anything)

Comment: what do u mean the source file or what??

Comment: @sanojlawrence Yes, the .woff, .tff, etc., those files have to be referenced somewhere since we're dealing with a custom font

Comment: That font is not being loaded as a font file. It is coming from your operating system (or if not present, a substitute is being used based on the order in the css file).

Comment: Right click, "inspect element", check the computed font property. Dev tools -> network tab -> "search". Type the font name. Not there? System font. There? found it. In this case, my browsers don't apply LucidaGrand, the test uses Lucida Sans Unicode, instead, which it got from my OS.